# Version compatibility

Tags: android, titanium

Trying to add `ti.admob` on a project and seems like anything I do it doesn't really work. I've tried several versions for this module, titanium sdk or android sdk, cleaning the project, restarting ti studio but nothing works. Most of the time I get this error message

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
```

Does anyone have an idea at least what versions are compatible?

What I have tried:

```
Titanium SDK 2.1.3, 3.1.0
ti.admob 2.0, 2.1
android sdk 2.2, 4.0.3
```

Comment: seems like maybe your manifest is structured incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem doesn't have anything to do with Admob I guess. At least Admob works for me ;-)

Here's a Resulution that worked - and is discussed in the official Appcelerator QA:

> There are a number of reasons that this can happen. Firstly, are you
>   setting an application name in the correct format, which is
>   com.yourcompany.appname? Pay attention to the hint text of the field
>   before you type anything. Also, file or folder names containing
>   non-ascii characters can cause problems. Lastly, if you have any
>   non-ascii characters in your js files, you need to ensure that the
>   files are encoded using utf8.
>
> [Source](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/114521/error-error-generating-rjava-from-manifest)

It might be useful if you post your appconfig.